# Why does giving params into url work, while giving params separately occurs an error?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I'm using python requests module, and the two ways result in different results.

Giving params into url:

```
url = 'http://my_url?m=getMember&mail=abc@de.com'
requests.get(url=url).json()
```

Giving params separately:

```
url = 'http://my_url'
data = {'m': 'getMember', 'mail':'abc@de.com'}
requests.get(url = url, data = data).json() #also tried 'data = json.dumps(data)'
```

The first way gives the right result.

But the second way occurs the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home1/irteam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And both have the response codes of 200.

```
>>> r = requests.post(url = url, data = json.dumps(data))
>>> r
<Response [200]>

>>> r = requests.post(url = url, data = data)
>>> r
<Response [200]>
```

When I type r.text,

```
>>> r.text
''
```

What could be the difference between the two?

Thanks:)

Comment: Check the response status code and try printing resp.text

Comment: @Sushanth Both have 200 response. What do you mean `resp.text`?? what should be `text` here??

Comment: Just, type ``r.text`` see wats the response from server.

Comment: @Sushanth An empty string shows up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By passing `data` argument you are sending a payload with `get` request. But not setting the params.
For setting `params` there is another argument. So this would work:

```
requests.get(url = url, params = data).json()
```

Hope this helps.